# Simples Vuejs route guard with password only

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

So, I'm trying to make a route guard where a user is prompted for a password before being redirected to a dashboard, but with everything setup I still can access the dashboard by typing /dashboard at the address bar.
What I have:

```
export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/dashboard',
      name: 'dashboard',
      component: home,
      props: true,
      beforeEnter: (to, from, next) =>{
        if (to.params.senha == to.params.mestre){
          next()
        } else{
          next({name: 'login'})
        }
      }
```

where 'senha' is the users input and 'mestre' is a stored variable master password in the login component data.

And this is what is sent by the login component to the router

```
toApp() {
      this.$router.push({
        name: "dashboard",
        params: { senha: this.senha, mestre: this.mestre }
      });
```

I know it is not a safe method for authing or anything related, its very simple for a very simple application.

what I am missing?

Comment: What are you getting in the browser console then directly approaching the `dashboard` path?

Answer (score 1):

The above logic works fine and there is no bug found

try to hardcode the values from router push and test

```
this.$router.push({
        name: "dashboard",
        params: { senha: "senha", mestre: "senha" }
      });
```

If it works fine, then try to print the value in console before routing

```
console.log(this.senha, this.mestre);
this.$router.push({
        name: "dashboard",
        params: { senha: this.senha, mestre: this.mestre }
      });
```

Still if you find any issue, try to check the console for any errors

Comment: So, I hardcoded senha and mestre in the router and was still able to navigate just by typing  '/dashboard' what I did was console log what the router had to compare:

 `beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
        if (to.params.senha == to.params.mestre){
          console.log(to.params.senha)
          console.log(to.params.mestre)
          next()`


and both of them returned as undefined